# LLVM: how to specify carry flag arithmetics?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I just managed to add two registers using

```
def ADD_reg3 : InstReg3Simple<0b01000, (outs GPR:$Wd), (ins GPR:$Wb, GPR:$Ws),
    "add\t$Wb, $Ws, $Wd",
    [(set GPR:$Wd, (add GPR:$Wb, GPR:$Ws))]>
{}
```

Great! Now I want to add two 'long' numbers.

It seems that LLVM is cool enough to automatically split this using two registers per number. Now my brand new compiler complains that it cannot select the 'adde' instruction for the higher words. I know that I will also need the 'addc' variant instead of 'add' for the lower words.

- How to specify addc and adde instructions?
  Do I have to define a carry resource first and how do I use it in the pattern, or is it all implicit and can I just exchange 'add' for 'addc/e'?
- My processor only has ADD and ADDC opcodes. Both generate the carry, but only ADDC also uses it. How can I tell LLVM that add and addc should get mapped to the same ADD opcode (with the carry not used for add)?

I tried to read this up but found that the easy examples stop short of multi word arithmetics while the real world code is much too complex for me to see what's going on.

UPDATE:

I found out that I can define an instruction for 'adde' (using opcode ADDC) just like above. Now llvm complains about missing 'addc'. When I change the 'add' pattern to 'addc', multi-word instruction works... but now, single word instructions cannot get selected any more because of missing 'add'!

So is boils down to: how can I map 'add' to 'addc', or both to some other whatever-thing?

Answer (score 0):

PARTIALLY SOLVED: I hacked single-word add/subtract by defining

```
def : Pat<(add GPR:$Wb, GPR:$Ws), (ADD_reg3 GPR:$Wb, GPR:$Ws)>;
def : Pat<(add GPR:$Wb, uimm5:$lit), (ADD_reg2_lit5 GPR:$Wb, uimm5:$lit)>;
...
```

for all kinds of ADD_* and SUB_* instruction definitions, all of which use addc / subc in their pattern and handle both the single-word and and lower multi-word math. There are similar versions for the upper words (using adde / sube).

Unfortunately I have to do this for each new add / subtract variant. I suspect there are more clever ways to do this!